# How to capture the file size from a URL and use it in Shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, centos

```
URL_C="any url"
length_C=$(curl -sI $URL_C | grep Content-Length | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
answer_C=$(awk -v len=$length_C 'BEGIN{printf "%.0f\n", len/1024}')
```

Will the variable `$answer_C` capture the file size ?

Is `Content-Length` the correct way ?

Comment: `size=$(curl -si "$url" | awk '/Content-Length/{print $2}')` should store the Content-Length value to a variable, but it won't work for "any_url", as some servers don't always output this header.

Comment: @Kenavoz: Lets say the content header is present. The content header has a certain value. 
Now I download that file on to my server, and I compare the file size (both from URL and system). It isn't the same. Does that mean after downloading, the size of the file on the disk increases. I want to be able to equate them

Comment: The file size should be the same after downloading. You can compare `Content-Length` value with `wc -c < "yourfile"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve headers, then try to `awk` the `Content-Length` value as @user000001 suggested, and if not found, download file to count chars :

```
url="your_url"
size=$(curl -sI "$url" | awk '/Content-Length/{gsub("\\r", ""); print $2}')
if [ -z "$size" ]; then 
    size=$(curl -s "$url" | wc -c)
fi
printf "%s : %d bytes\n" "$url" "$size"
```

Note : `gsub("\\r", "")` in the awk command is for removing carriage returns from the curl output.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894. Updated.